# Bash how to parse log and check differently formatted lines match

Tags: regex, bash, logging, grep, sh

I have a log file I'm trying to parse that looks a bit like this with other lines omitted

```
[10:44:20] [4m[36m$ -PATH /users/helloworld/folder[0m
...
[10:44:21] ▸ [35m-PATH[0m
[10:44:21] ▸ [35m/users/helloworld/folder[0m
```

I want to have a small script to say if the first and second occurrences of -PATH match /users/helloworld/folder

I'm not sure how to account for the first occurrence being on the *same* line, and the second occurrence appearing on the *next* line

And then afterwards being able to echo "MATCHED" or "DIDNT MATCH" depending on whether those occurrences are the same.

I'm fairly new to regex/grep so finding it hard to get my head around this kinda thing, thanks in advance.

Comment: this line `[10:44:21] ▸ [35m-PATH[0m` seems to be corrupted

Comment: `grep '/users/helloworld/' file`?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood you need to print matches of paths in logs and print them if their count is 2, if this is the case then could you please try following.

```
awk '
match($0,/\/[^\[]*/){
  a[substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)]++
}
END{
  for(i in a){
    if(a[i]==2){
       print "MATCHED for path " i,a[i]
    }
    else{
       print " DID NOT match for path ",i,a[i]
    }
  }
}'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
MATCHED for path /users/helloworld/folder 2
```